# Tfs - Cannot be merged. Please try with another solution

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

[image]

I'm trying to get latest version of solution, however, this error occured everytime, I tried with another solutions, but fails.

Is there anyone else who faced this problem in advance ? Or anyone who knows to work out this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

According to your error screenshot, this kind of issue may related to cache. Suggest you first backup the pending changes in VS (local changes), then [clear both VS and TFS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsalm/2013/12/17/how-to-clear-the-tfs-cache-on-client-machines/). Then try to get latest again.

If above solution not work, the issue still exists, you could **delete local workspace** (also backup local files), create a totally new workspace, then get the latest version from server, back up changes, which should do the trick.